# Visual Studio 2010 : Is this possible to disable the "Copy Nothing" in this IDE?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When accidentally I double hit a CTRL-X, my selection of code is cut, but the clipboard is empty because the second CTRL-X has cut something like "empty selection" or what so ever. This is really painful, and to me has no sense to allow to cut or copy "nothing", or "empty selection".
Since it's specific to Visual Studio, I wonder if there is a way to disable it?

Comment: Strange. The behaviour I see is that whole line is cut instead. When current line is empty, the behaviour can be contolled by "Apply Cut or Copy commands to blank lines..." options, but when it is not empty, the Cut of the whole line is always done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Tools/Options, select Text Editor and then pick either "All Languages" or a specific language.

There's an option there for "Apply Cut or Copy commands to blank lines when there is no selection."  Disable that and I believe it'll help.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks a lot. I've have been across all the sub menus and missed that one! Long live to SO!